# What layout for a nearly empty web app?

Tags: website-design, web-app, layout, page-layout

### Context

I am designing an ad hoc enterprise web app that is very simple: given two parameters (year, month), click a button that generates and let you download a file (an Excel spreadsheet). Users are data analysts, and would only use the app couple times a month. The app is to be accessed on a computer, via a web page.

### Problem

This makes that, beyond header (logo, app title) and footer (legal and other corporate one-liner blurb), **the app is constituted of only 3 elements: 2 drop-down menus, and one button.**

As the corporate style-guide is flat-design oriented, there is a lot of empty space on the page and it feels too roomy and quite wrong — even with already fairly large font-size

### Question

**How to make a nearly empty web app not look like an empty apartment?**

I have looked at very limited interface apps like WeTransfer, but they have (at least) twice as much elements, and their strategy to “fill the void” by using a picture wouldn't work in a corporate environment.

Comment: Something you can consider e.g Gmail sign in (done through cards), Atlassian sign in [cards + illustration]. You can either leave it empty or think of using illustration

Comment: Your question is essentially (at its core) about websites that are empty.  However, the way you've asked it is more like a review that's specific to your site.  I'm closing your question so that you can edit it to be more general and useful to others.  When you've done that, it can be reopened.

Comment: @JohnGB thanks for your feedback. I understand your concern, yet I disagree with your interpretation: I've deliberately not put a wireframe of my design, to not bias answers and focus on the question itself (which I tried to phrase in a way that it is generic). I detail an example only to clarify the problem/question. So I'm not sure I'd know how to make the question more generic, but, anyway, I'll accept one of the answer below (so I don't mind the question remaining closed).

Comment: @ebosi You're trying to get feedback on something that you're doing.  That isn't how this site works.  You need to ask a broader UX specific question that other people who read it can also learn from or apply to solve their UX problems.  So, as long as you're trying to ask about something specific to your site or app, it won't meet the requirements of this site.  On the other hand if you break down your question to the root UX problem you're facing, and then ask a question on that root problem, you should be okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a non-problem. The objective of your tool is for the user to download a spreadsheet, so the easier it is for them to do so, the better. No additional bells and whistles are needed. In fact, adding more stuff might distract them from the main task.

You could optimize small things such as instead of using drop-downs, providing a simpler interface such as a calendar selection. Such decisions can take up more space and ease the usability.

Your tool is more functional and task-based than anything, therefore aim for simplicity. Think about checkout process forms or customization step process forms, they are intentionally stripped of all essential items to help the user focus and accomplish one task.

Additionally you could provide a title and simple instructions or a description of what the tool does. Maybe someone encounters a problem and need to contact someone, all that small helpful content can exist in the page. What are some essential information a new user should know or can reference to for self-help?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem also for websites that consist only of a "coming soon" page. Most of them use large elements and a background image or illustration. But you can also play around with a bit of movement in the background to make it more lively or even give it depth. [This template is a good example](https://demo.w3layouts.com/demos_new/template_demo/22-02-2020/red-leaf-comingsoon-demo_Free/374722491/web/index.html) that I found after a quick search. It's a matter of searching for "under construction" or "coming soon" pages and get inspired!

Note: It doesn't have to be a photograph or some busy illustration. Using a more artistic, abstract, lighter, less busy illustration or line drawing for the background is also an option. If not, consider the "empty apartment" style to be better suited for the app. Any other ideas would probably only suggest to add clutter.